# Assistance with automating an SFTP transfer via R

Tags: r, ftp, rstudio, sftp, rcurl

I have an SFTP process I've been doing manually.

**Note: None of what I'm about to write are my actual login credentials, so please do not bring it up in the comments.**

My manual process has looked like this.

1. Open the terminal
2. Enter `open ftp://ftp.info.com/jsmith/Up`
3. FTP client opens up and asks for my username and password
4. I enter my username: jsmith
5. I enter my password: testpassword123
6. I upload my file

How can I automate this entire process using R? What package do I use and what would the script look like?

Comment: Your title asks about SFTP, but you're clearly opening an FTP URL. SFTP and FTP are completely different protocols. What protocol do you want to use?

Comment: @Kenster My bad. I guess FTP?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows I would recommend to use [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/) or WinSCP. If on Linux use the builtin or OS-appropriate SFTP (check the `apt` or `yum` repos for versions appropriate to your OS). Personally I use `WinSCP` [scripts](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp). For Macintosh I recommend [CyberDuck](http://CyberDuck.io).

You can use these external programs for your SFTP / SCP transfers by use of the `system()` R function. This function will allow you to invoke any arbitrary command to pass to the OS.

Example:

```
system("open sftp://username:password@sftp.example.com/", intern = F)
```

Please see `?system` for more options and examples.

You can use an SSH key pair for passwordless authentication, or you can store your password as an environment variable (and pass in the value that way), or theoretically you could do it insecurely by putting the password right in the SFTP command inside of `system()`.

`system()` is the only R command in play, so beyond that you just follow the sytax of whatever SFTP program you choose. if your file has a name that's dynamically generated within R based on the date, then I'd generate a WinSCP script in the same way (pass in the file name with date, like you did with `paste` in the comment). Please see [this](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) for the commands, options, and WinSCP examples.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You'll have to forgive me because I'm totally unfamiliar with this stuff but what would it look like? I don't know what a lot of the stuff you just typed means haha

Comment: @wizkids121 Please see my updated answer for an example

Comment: Thank you, but where do I add this? At the end of my R script?

Comment: @wizkids121 You do it in R. It doesn't matter where in the R script, generally speaking. It would only matter if you wrote some other code that needs the result of this, then you'd need to put this before that code.

Comment: Got it. So it would look like this based on what I provided above?

`system("open sftp://jsmith:testpassword123@ftp.info.com/jsmith/Up/", intern = F)`

Comment: And wait, I'm still very confused. How does it know what file to upload?

@Hack-R

Comment: so lets my final lines look like this:

`currentDate <- Sys.Date()`


`csvTestData <- paste("/Users/jsmith/test_data", currentDate,".csv",sep="")`


`write.csv(sandwich, file = csvTestData, row.names = FALSE)`


So that is what creates the CSV I want to upload via this process

Comment: @wizkids121 Sorry, I was AFK. OK so system is the only R command in play, so beyond that you just follow the sytax of whatever SFTP program you choose. if your file has a name that's dynamically generated within R based on the date, then I'd generate a WinSCP script in the same way (pass in the file name with date, like you did with `paste` in the comment above). Please see this for the commands, options, and WinSCP examples https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting

Comment: Any chance we can move to a private chat about this? I'm really not sure what any of this means.

Comment: I should also note, this is using a MAC, not a Windows. Not sure if that matters here.

Comment: @wizkids121 It means that instead of using WinSCP you'll pick a different sftp program, but it doesn't change the answer. When I had a Mac I used https://cyberduck.io/ . Incidentally, you only capitalize MAC if you mean **M**edia **A**ccess **C**ontrol. Not Macintosh ;) Also, please feel free to use the green checkbox to mark this as the solution :)

Comment: Oh, I use Cyberduck. Haha and thanks for that. Good call on the capitalization.

Comment: Btw, you probably mean something like `system("winscp /command open ...")`, not `system("open ..")`.

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this is an ancient post but I'll answer anyway.

I had a similar struggle and ended up making a few transfer solutions in an R package called [{farrago}](https://github.com/al-obrien/farrago).

There are functions to transfer via winscp and curl, so hopefully that covers most bases discussed in prior comments. Here is one example function from the package:

```
transfer_curl <- function(file = NULL, direction = NULL, connection = NULL, handle_options = list(), drop_location = NULL) { 
  
   # Parameter checks 
   if (is.null(direction) || !(direction %in% c("upload", "download"))) stop("Invalid direction input, use 'upload' or 'download' keywords") 
   if (is.null(file)) stop("Please provide a file to upload or download") 
   if (is.null(connection)) stop("No connection (URL) value was provided. Username and password can be provided under handle_options.") 
   if (is.null(drop_location) && direction == "download") stop("Drop location must be provided for downloading.") 
  
   if(direction == "download"){ 
  
     # Create handle 
     hdl <- curl::new_handle() 
     curl::handle_setopt(handle = hdl, .list = handle_options) 
  
     # Create URL 
     urlfile <- file.path(connection, file) 
     dropfile <- file.path(drop_location, file) 
  
     # Download file 
     curl::curl_download(urlfile, destfile = dropfile, handle = hdl) 
  
   } else if (direction == "upload") { 
  
     # Create URL 
     urlfile <- file.path(connection, basename(file)) 
     upload_object <- do.call(curl::curl_upload, c(file = file, url = urlfile, handle_options)) # Not returned as other details already provided... 
   } 
 }
```